# list comprehension multiple and dependant levels

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to make a list comprehension with multiple for.
To make it more difficult, I have dependencies between the two levels.
The higher, `app.containers` is a list of containers, and it contains some `contents`, also iterable.

This dictionary, at the end, should contain some pointers to the whole application contents, accessible by its name, prefixed with the one of its containers.

```
prefixed_names = {".".join(container.name, content.name): content
                  for content in container.contents
                  for container in app.containers}
```

Python throws a `NameError`, arguying that `container` is not defined.

Comment: You should change the two `for` loops position to solve the problem. The first is the outer loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension is a convenient way of writing nested `for` loops. The first `for` expression is the outmost `for` so you need to swap the order in which you have written your `for` expressions. As an example:

```
>>> [ a+b for a in 'san' for b in '123' ]
['s1', 's2', 's3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3']

>>> for a in 'san':
...     for b in '123':
...             print a+b,
...
s1 s2 s3 a1 a2 a3 n1 n2 n3
```

Comment: Not very intuitive... indeed it worked perfectly. Sorry for that. I could have read the manual for this question. :) Thank you !

Comment: @carrieje You could accept the answer too so that it benefits others :-)

Comment: I was about to do it. I would do it as soon as the app will let me do it ^^

Answer (score 0):

In the expresstion

```
... for content in container.contents for container in app ....
```

you have an internal variable `container` which will replace the external variable `container`. See if

```
... for content in container.contents for c in app ....
```

helps. Here, even I cant figure out which `container` you want to refer to in the `join` statement.